# How take a Screenshot in Floating Window Mode with MediaProjection API?

Tags: android, kotlin, service, android-mediaprojection

I'm trying to take a screenshot after I minimize my App and enter Floating Window Mode (like Facebook Messenger) so when I click on the minimized icon, I can take a screenshot. I found some relevant samples on screen capture: https://gist.github.com/ch8n/73b937d49b4347e0cab113b038ba6046 and Mirroring without capture: https://github.com/android/media-samples/tree/main/ScreenCapture  but didn't find any example about the usage with services and jetpack compose and eventually how to use it together. The wished behavior is like in the added picture.[image]

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val TAG = "MainActivity"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MisInfoTheme {
                Column(
                    Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .padding(16.dp),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ) {
                    Button(onClick = {
                        startService(Intent(this@MainActivity, FloatingWindowService::class.java))

                    }) {
                        Text(text = "Floating Widget")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FloatingWindowScreen.kt

```
@Composable
fun floatWindowScreen() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
            .width(200.dp)
            .height(50.dp)
            .background(Color.LightGray),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
        ClickableText(
            text = AnnotatedString("On click take screenshot and disoplay it in the original app"),
            onClick = {
                Toast.makeText(context, "TODO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        )
    }
}
```

FloatingWindowService.kt

```
class FloatingWindowService : Service() {
    private val TAG = "FloatingWindowService"
    private var resultCode = 0
    private val windowManager get() = getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
    private val params = initWindowManagerParams()

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? = null


    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        drawFloatingWindow()
    }


    private fun initWindowManagerParams(): WindowManager.LayoutParams {

        val paramType = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
        } else {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE
        }

        val paramFlags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS or
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE or
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL or
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH

        val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            0,
            0,
            paramType,
            paramFlags,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        )

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP or Gravity.LEFT

        return params
    }

    private fun drawFloatingWindow() {
        val composeView = ComposeView(this)
        composeView.setContent {
            floatWindowScreen()
        }

        // Trick The ComposeView into thinking we are tracking lifecycle
        val viewModelStore = ViewModelStore()
        val lifecycleOwner = FloatingWindowLifeCycleOwner()
        lifecycleOwner.performRestore(null)
        lifecycleOwner.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
        ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(composeView, lifecycleOwner)
        ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner.set(composeView) { viewModelStore }
        composeView.setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner(lifecycleOwner)

        windowManager.addView(composeView, params)
    }
}
```